# DetachedInstanceError: Instance <> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Thanks for reading.

I am probably doing something unintelligent -- I am a relatively new database user.

This is the full stack trace of the error:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError

DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Event at 0x7f514c79bc10> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
Traceback (most recent call last)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/contrib/fixers.py", line 152, in __call__

    return self.app(environ, start_response)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app

    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

    File "/home/rodda/workspace/turbo-guacamole/app/authentication_methods.py", line 44, in check_user

    return func(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/rodda/workspace/turbo-guacamole/app/admin_views.py", line 63, in admin_publicize

    start_time = event.start_time

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 237, in __get__

    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 578, in get

    value = state._load_expired(state, passive)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 474, in _load_expired

    self.manager.deferred_scalar_loader(self, toload)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 610, in load_scalar_attributes

    (state_str(state)))

    DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Event at 0x7f514c79bc10> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

The code that generates this error is the following:

```
events = models.Event.query.filter_by(classification = 'ais').all()
for event in events:
    start_time = event.start_time
```

I query Events from many other parts of my Flask app and I don't run into problems.  The problem only exists when I query the specific events with their classification set as ais.

Most interestingly, however, when I run the same precise code in the Python shell, it doesn't throw an error.

There was no difference in how I created these events from how I created other events.

Ideas?

Thank you very much.

P.S. Preferably I don't want to reload all of these events (there are about 400 of them).  If there is a way to fix this without recreating all of them that would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

events is a list

```
 start_time = []
 events = models.Event.query.filter_by(classification = 'ais').all()
 for event in events:
     start_time.append(event.start_time)
```

this gives you a list of all event.start_time.

Comment: I think you found an error in the logic of the MRE which is unrelated to this problem.